# Javascript HTML5 video video.currentTime.toFixed(5);

Tags: html, html5-video, video.js

Currently I am using the code `this.video.currentTime.toFixed(5);`

```
(2524.31708)
```

I know the left number is seconds but I cannot find out what the right number is I would have assumed it was milliseconds but there are only 1000 milliseconds in a second so it can't be that, if anyone can advise it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `0.31708` to be given in milliseconds and one second has `1000` milliseconds, you can make: `0.31708 * 1000` as it would be between `0` and `1000`.

Here's your updated code:

```js
var a = 2524.31708;
a = a + "";
a = a.split(".");
a = (parseFloat("0." + a[1]) * 1000);
alert(a);
```

In this case, there is `317.08` milliseconds. Yes, milliseconds can be in decimals too, which is ultimately small to find with naked eyes. `;)`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the question poorly what I am trying to say is that I know the left value is seconds and one would assume the right value is milliseconds but there are only 1000 milliseconds in a second so this value cannot be milliseconds - so i would like to know what is it.

Comment: @DanielPremier Give `.toFixed(4)` instead.

Comment: to fixed will just trim 1 more character off the end.

Comment: @DanielPremier I don't understand. Check my update and see if it works?

Comment: It won't work 3170 is not a valid time in milliseconds that would be 3 seconds and 170 milliseconds are we sure the second number is milliseconds and not micro seconds or something like that?

Comment: @DanielPremier Woah woah... Now I understood what you are telling. It should be like this... Wait...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime - tells me it returns in seconds this is not the case because seconds are whole and don't have decimals!

Comment: @DanielPremier Man, I solved it. Check the final update.

Comment: Sorry I think you are missing the point behind the question here, I am not trying to do the math but instead i am trying to find out what this.video.currentTime.toFixed(5); is returning after the decimal point.

Comment: @DanielPremier It is the seconds in decimal buddy. Seconds could mean half a second or `500` milliseconds. Or in this case, `317.08` milliseconds or `0.31708` seconds. Can there be `317.08` milliseconds?